# Nuxt 3 Layers and Azure DevOps repositories

Tags: azure-devops, layer, nuxtjs3

Has anyone implemented Nuxt Layers using links to Azure DevOps Git repositories.

Trying to figure out if we even can yet, or if we can, what else is required like an auth token for private repos etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct link in Nuxt 3 layer to Azure DevOps repo. As per the [link](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/going-further/layers#git-repository), it supports github, gitlab, bitbucket.

[image]

Tried with azure devops repo with two formats, it **cannot** extend the repo, it could be not supported.

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  extends: [
    'azure-devops:org/project/_git/repo',
    'azure-devops:org/project',
  ]
})
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for confirming @wade-zhou-msft, I know it did not reference DevOps, but it also does not specifically say that it does NOT support DevOps... the docs are quite ambiguous which is frustrating. There's another repo mentioned starting with S but I forget what it is now.

I think someone will need to create a provider in unjs/giget to handle DevOps repos. It is unfortunately above my level of knowledge to add myself.

Comment: Yes, the doc is ambiguous on the repos supported, so i checked with the two formats above. Or you can also confirm the query on link [here](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues) where Nuxt experts could clarify more details.